# find when a column exceeds a value and place a value in the next column on its first occurence only

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Here are 2 columns in excel with 2 columns, columnA and columnB, column A is just some numbers getting higher as we go down through the column. Column B is what I `Want to achieve`

```
        Want to achieve 
168094  
173137  
178331  
183681  360000
189191  
194867  
200713  
206734  
212936  
219324  
225904  
232681  
239662  
246852  
254257  
261885  
269741  
277834  
286169
```

I want to be able to achieve the 2nd column `Want to achieve` which is empty except for one row where it has a value of 3600 on the first occurrence where col A is greater than 180000. **How can I achieve this?** I have tried this using various helper columns but cannot get what I want.

I was hoping to achieve it without vba, if possible.

Comment: The first occurance of a cell that is greater than 180,000 okay, but why 360,000? In your table, you have 360,000, but in your paragraph you have 3,600?

Comment: tks, just an arbitrary number for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(A1<180000,A2>=180000),360000,"")
```

[image]

Comment: tk you I got there in the end but it was not as good as that. I was using 3 helper columns to achieve it.